# meaning of “has strong overtones with”

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't figure out the meaning of “has strong overtones with” in the paragraph below（it's in the last sentence，does that mean “imply” or something？（I am from china，and i hope i had made my question clear）

here is the paragraph：

> Shamanism is a potent source of fantasy and self-delusion. Alan
>   Parker’s film The Wall(1982) emphasized the thin line between rock
>   shamanism and Fascism. The concentration on image, might and moral
>   certainty occurs in both genres. In 1976 David Bowie outraged the media
>   and many of his fans by apparently greeting them with a Nazi salute when
>   he arrived at Victoria railway station from the Continent. The press publicised his comment made to a Swedish reporter that ‘Britain could benefit
>   from a Fascist leader’. Not surprisingly, Bowie later recanted, and explained
>   his flirtation with Nazism as a by-product of physical and psychological
>   exhaustion. However, the mythologizing aspects of Nazism, notably the
>   passionate concern with regeneration and the search for new order, **has
>   strong overtones with** the myths of finding spiritual wholeness and
>   emotional integration through worshiping the Übermensch, the prototypal
>   celebrity in Nietzsche’s philosophy.

Answer (score 2):

The literal definition of *overtone* is musical:

> [**overtone**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overtone) (n): 1. A musical tone which is a part of the harmonic series above a fundamental note, and may be heard with it.

The *overtone* is not the main note, but other, subtle notes that can be heard above the main note.  This helps us understand the figurative definition:

> 2. (often **overtones**) A subtle or subsidiary quality, implication, or connotation.

An "overtone" is something that is not said directly, but is strongly implied.  In this article, the writer says that the attraction of fascist doctrines (such as Nazism) *includes*, *relates to*, or *suggests* the worship of the metaphorical Übermensch.

That being said, "overtones *with*" is an odd-sounding expression.  "Overtones *of* is more idiomatic.

> Many of his speeches have been popular but profoundly disturbing, with their **overtones of** nationalism, racism, and xenophobia.

Answer (score 1):

"Has stong overtones with"

In essence the, writer is trying to convey, that the aspects of Mythology in Nazism, is both; connected to and overlaps with the myth's held in Nietzsche's philosophy, relating to an Übermensch.

"**overtone**"

a subtle or subsidiary quality, implication, or connotation.

"the decision may have political overtones"

Comment: Thank you so much！I kind of understand its meaning.